# Image Carousel script stops after last image. Need it to repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I need my script to repeat after the last image is displayed.  How can I go about resetting what the script has done then making it play again?  The script changes the z-index of the current image.  After the last image how can I make the script 'reset' the z-index of all the images and re-run from the top?  Thanks!

```
<script>
function cycleImages(){
  var $active = $('#carousel .active');
  var $next = ($('#carousel .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#carousel .active').next() : $('#carousel img:first');
  $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
  $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
  $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
  $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
  if ($('#carousel .active').next().length > 0) setTimeout('cycleImages()',1000);//check for a next image, and if one exists, call the function recursively
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // run every 7s
  setTimeout('cycleImages()', 1000);
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check again if there is a next .active element when setting a new Timeout

use just

```
setTimeout('cycleImages()',1000);
```

instead of

```
if ($('#carousel .active').next().length > 0) setTimeout('cycleImages()',1000);
```

Comment: Oh wow haha!  Thank you so much!  I was making more work than necessary then!

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic would be to check if the images have reached the end by comparing the **.length** with the total no of images (full length). if yes then go to first image i.e

`('#carousel .active').first()`

and call

`setTimeout('cycleImages()',1000);`

happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I figured it out already, @Matei Mihai helped me!

Answer (score 0):

instead of bringing the next element to front, you can send the active element back by maintaning the counter for z-index, like

```
<script>
var zCount = 0;
function cycleImages(){
  var $active = $('#carousel .active');
  var $next = ($('#carousel .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#carousel .active').next() : $('#carousel img:first');

  $active.fadeOut(1500, function(){//fade out the top image
    $active.css('z-index', --zCount).show().removeClass('active'); //send the active image at the bottom of all images and unhide the image
    $next.addClass('active'); //make the next image as active
    setTimeout('cycleImages()',1000);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout('cycleImages()', 1000);
})

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I figured it out already, @Matei Mihai helped me!